# Nesting JSON-Arrays in a json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to embed a JArray as a value in a JObject.
For the sake of simplicity I have the following string that I'd like to parse:
`"{"SERVICE":"["ABC"]"}"`

And this is my code:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JObject jTemp = null;

            string temp = "{\"SERVICE\":\"[\"ABC\"]\"}";
            jTemp = JObject.Parse(temp);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

An exception is being thrown when trying to parse the string pointing to the letter A of "ABC".
The exception message is: "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: A. Path 'SERVICE', line 1, position 14."

I hope that someone can point out my mistake, or at least what am I missing here.

Answer (score 4):

Your array is currently a string:

```
string temp = "{\"SERVICE\":\"[\"ABC\"]\"}";
```

Try changing it to this:

```
string temp = "{\"SERVICE\":[\"ABC\"]}";
```

Comment: ok, and now nest 'temp' in a json-array. How would that look? Because C# apparently wraps quotes around the array.